# Seperate Slim from HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, slim

So I am confused on how to properly implement the Slim Framework into my use case.

I have a web app html/css/javascript that can not have PHP in it.

All I want to do is use Slim to do some simple GET requests via ajax.

How do I start the App to handle requests if it is never touched int he index.html file?

I'm guessing this has something to do with the .htacess file but not finding anything useful in my initial search.

Comment: If you are using slim you are still writing php.  Why can't you use php?

Comment: I will be using phonegap is why no PHP in the html files...just want to use Slim for AJAX calls only.

Comment: Your html files can still point to a php file outside of your app.  You will need to install slim on your server then create some php files and place them on the server.  Then you have your ajax functions call the URLs of those php files.

Answer (score 0):

Got some help on this from the Slim Discussion board.

Here is the answer and example.

Yes, the .htaccess file ensures that any request is handled by a single file (usually index.php but you could name it anything you want).

Your Ajax calls would presumably go to different URLs. Those requests would all be handled by the Slim app.

[Example Here](http://clintberry.com/2012/backbone-js-apps-authentication-tutorial/)